# Bit-perfect USB Audio gadget

Tags: audio, gadget

I want to use Raspberry Pi Zero as a **USB DAC** with **switchable sample rate**. Maximum resolution should be 96/24 with all 4 common rates ie. 44.1, 48, 88.2 an 96 kHz supported. It should also work with Windows. I don't care about volume control but it would be nice to have it.

I tried to connect Raspberry as a DAC to a smartphone and it worked up to 48 kHz. Since the script I managed to download did not implement "clock entities", it only had one sample rate and, albeit detected, did not start on Windows. Later I changed it to UAC1, Windows error disappeared but didn't play.

By the way, Raspberry seems to have timing problems with USB DACs connected in OTG mode; the only one fully working for me was PCM2704. USB itself is fast enough and DLNA works via RNDIS all the way to 192/32, consuming <25% CPU.

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

modprobe libcomposite

cd /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/
mkdir g1 && cd g1

echo 0x1d6b > idVendor  # Linux Foundation
echo 0x0104 > idProduct # Multifunction Composite Gadget
echo 0x0100 > bcdDevice # v1.0.0
echo 0x0200 > bcdUSB    # USB 2.0
echo 0x01   > bDeviceClass
echo 0x02   > bDeviceSubClass
echo 0x20   > bDeviceProtocol

mkdir -p strings/0x409
echo "deadbeef00115599" > strings/0x409/serialnumber
echo "irq5 labs"        > strings/0x409/manufacturer
echo "Pi Zero Gadget"   > strings/0x409/product

mkdir -p functions/uac2.usb0   # audio
echo 3          > functions/uac2.usb0/c_chmask
echo 48000      > functions/uac2.usb0/c_srate
echo 4          > functions/uac2.usb0/c_ssize
echo 3          > functions/uac2.usb0/p_chmask
echo 48000      > functions/uac2.usb0/p_srate
echo 4          > functions/uac2.usb0/p_ssize

mkdir -p configs/c.1
echo 250 > configs/c.1/MaxPower
mkdir -p configs/c.1/strings/0x409
echo "Audio" > configs/c.1/strings/0x409/configuration
ln -s functions/uac2.usb0 configs/c.1/

echo 1       > os_desc/use
echo 0xcd    > os_desc/b_vendor_code
echo MSFT100 > os_desc/qw_sign
ln -s configs/c.1 os_desc

#udevadm settle -t 5 || :
ls /sys/class/udc/ > UDC
```

So the question is, what to change in the script, or what other method to use to achieve at least UAC1 USB audio gadget with switchable sample rates?

Comment: did you figure out how to do this.. I am quite interested in this process